# jQuery - how to detect an option being selected in a select, when it doesn't change the selection

Tags: jquery, events, drop-down-menu, listener

I have a bunch of selects listing PDF files.  When the user chooses a PDF from the select, I display the pdf in the screen.  This is triggered from an event listener on "change blur".

If they then close the div with the pdf in it, and want to open it again, they must select it again from the dropdown.

However, I'm finding that in order to show the pdf again, they need to select a *different* pdf, then open the select again and choose the one they do want:  in other words, if you open the select, then click "Done" (on mobile) or click on the already-selected option (desktop), then because it hasn't changed, it doesn't trigger showing the PDF.

I thought that adding "blur" to the events being listened for would do it - wouldn't the select closing trigger it's blur event?  But it doesn't seem to help.

This is my code:

```
$("body").on("change blur", ".pdf-file-select", function(e){
  //get the pdf uri from the selection and show the pdf
});
```

thanks.

EDIT - on investigation, `blur` only fires when I click outside the select - it doesn't fire when I close the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `click` event instead

```
$("body").on("click", ".pdf-file-select", function(e){
  //get the pdf uri from the selection and show the pdf
});
```

Comment: That will fire when they open the select though, right, so I'd need to check that something is selected before proceeding?

Comment: @MaxWilliams please accept this as the answer if it helped you.

Comment: This worked great, thanks.  I just assumed click would be fired by the click that opens the select, but it appears that it isn't.